# Only master branch is visible after cloning a Git repo

Tags: git

I am working on a project and I created a repository with a `master` branch. Someone who is working on it added a branch named `new-branch` -- their code changes are in this branch.

However, when I clone the repository:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:me/my-repo.git
```

I can clone it successfully, but it only shows the `master` branch. I do not know how I can view/get the `new-branch`.

How would I pull this branch to my repository?

Comment: Just for the record - `pull != clone`. In `git` these are two very different concepts.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you clone a repository, all remote branches are created as "remote tracking branches" in your repository. These aren't shown by default, but you can see these with:

```
git branch -a
```

If you do a `git checkout new-branch`, git will find the remote tracking branch of the same name, automatically create a new local branch from the same commit, and switch to the new local branch.

For future work, the `git fetch` command will update all the remote tracking branches with their latest commit from the remote.

Comment: Didnt know that worked - I thought you need the -b on checkout to create a new branch

Comment: @Adrian Cornish: this DWIM behaviour has been present since git 1.6.6, introduced in [70c9ac2f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c9ac2f1999b7e0c17a864235537cffe29dfea4)

Comment: What happens if I am disconnected? "remote tracking branches" sounds like they are not physically present in the cloned repo. Would git checkout <existing-branch> work if I have just found it via git branch -a in a disconnected state? Would git branch -a list the branch in that state at all?

Comment: @timmkrause: Despite the name, remote tracking branches *are* physically present in your cloned repo. They mirror the same named branch on the server. A checkout of a remote tracking branch will work while disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i cloned the Repo correctly but i was trying to find the branches in the internal folder. so i was unable to see any.

My Project has below folder structure.

```
ABC/
ABC_XYZ / 
ABC_Core
ABC_Web
x
y
z
.....
```

so i was trying to check the branches in ABC_XYZ instead of ABC.