# can not get new branch from github

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

my co-worker has just create a new branch in the git repository which we have been working for a while. but in my local repository, I am having a hard time to get the new branch and merge it into my local repos. I found this post: [Only master branch is visible after cloning a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889753/git-branch-not-showing), but it did not work for me.

- when I try `git branch -r`, I don't see the new branch name listed,
- when I try `git fetch`, it says no remote repos specified,
- when I try `git fetch newbranchname`, it says `newbranchname` does not appear to be a repos,
- when I try `git chechout newbranchname`, it says `newbranchname` did not match
  any file known to git.

what else can I try? please kindly help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Has your co-worker pushed the new branch to the repository you're trying to fetch from? Does it show up in `git remote show <remotename>`?

Comment: yes, that is for sure, I can see the new branch from github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `git fetch` is supposed to be a repository, not a branch.

```
$ git fetch origin
From https://github.com/...
 * [new branch]    newbranchname  -> origin/newbranchname

$ git checkout -b newbranchname origin/newbranchname
 Branch newbranchname set up to track remote branch newbranchname from origin.
 Switched to a new branch 'newbranchname'
```

You should now have a local copy of your coworker's branch from which you can `git push` and `git pull` to update.

Comment: Hi, @vergenzt, thanks for your reply. when I try `git fetch origin`, it also says the origin does not appear to be a git repos. do I miss anything. thanks.

Comment: What output does `git remote` give you?

Comment: it gives me the remote repository name.

Comment: Use that remote repository name instead of `origin`.  I had incorrectly assumed that you had used the default.