# Git is not showing all branches on local

Tags: git, github, moodle, git-remote

I forked a repo from Github. On doing `git remote -v` it displays:

```
origin  https://github.com/myusername/moodle.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myusername/moodle.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git (push)
```

The `moodle.git` has about 10 branches, but the repo shows only 2 of them. On doing `git branch -a` (show all branches) I get:

```
  MOODLE_24_STABLE// just these two on local..how?
* master//
  origin/MOODLE_13_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_14_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_15_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_16_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_17_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_18_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_19_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_20_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_21_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_22_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_23_STABLE
  origin/MOODLE_24_STABLE
  origin/master
  upstream/MOODLE_13_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_14_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_15_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_16_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_17_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_18_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_19_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_20_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_21_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_22_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_23_STABLE
  upstream/MOODLE_24_STABLE
  upstream/master
```

How do I resolve my problem without any loss of data or any irregularities?

Comment: Why would you expect more local branches? After cloning a repository, there's only one local master branch. Other branches are created on demand.

Comment: @knittl: Okay. I didn't know that. Would you please instruct me how to do it? I've created a branch say `git checkout -b STABLE_23_STABLE` but the files are not those of that branch.

Comment: `git checkout -b MOODLE_23_STABLE` creates a new branch off of the current commit, so you will still see the same commits. Either `git checkout -b MOODLE_23_STABLE upstream/MOODLE_23_STABLE` or `git checkout MOODLE_23_STABLE` (shorthand/DWIM syntax)

Comment: Duplicate of [Git branch not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889753/git-branch-not-showing)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cloning a repo won't duplicate all the remote branches on the local repo: for a large remote repo with a lot of branches, that would pollute your local namespace with tons of branches.

I have a [one-liner command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches/6300386#6300386) in order to create local branches tracking all the remote branches of a remote repo, but this is usually not needed.
You only create a local branch tracking a remote one when needed.

```
git checkout -b aBranch --track origin/aBranch

# or, shorter:
$ git checkout --track origin/aBranch 
Branch aBranch set up to track remote branch refs/remotes/origin/aBranch.
Switched to a new branch "aBranch"  

# even shorter at the end of this answer.
```

Adding a `--track` allows for setting up the configuration to mark the start-point branch as "**[upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)**" from the new branch.
This configuration will tell git to show the relationship between the two branches in `git status` and `git branch -v`.
Furthermore, it directs git pull without arguments to pull from the upstream when the new branch is checked out.

---

[kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix) mentions that `--track` is implied when forking a branch off a remote branch (unless `branch.autosetupmerge` is set to `false`)

This could be enough

```
git checkout aBranch
```

The exact explanation from [`git checkout` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is:

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch
```

Comment: `--track` is implied when forking a branch off a remote branch (unless `branch.autosetupmerge` is not set to `false`). I would also advise @xan, to take their time and read some [introductory material on remote branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) to not get lost later.

Comment: @kostix good point. I have added that precision to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: `git checkout --track origin/aBranch ` this solved the issue for me, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Some times , if you havn't pulled the latest code, you wont be allowed to checkout the newly created branch.Because your changes are not in synch.

So first 
-pull the latest
-checkout from newly created branch

Answer (score 0):

if your starting to initialise a repository :
1 - git reset
2 - delete .git reposytory
3 - git init
4 - You must commit a first commit