# Git push local branch to repo

Tags: git, branch

I'm trying to push my local branch (Dev) up to my git repo so that when someone else clones the repo, they will have the Dev branch as a local one.

So far, when you clone the repo and run `git branch -a` you get this:

```
master
remotes/origin/Dev
remotes/origin/master
```

but what I want the person to get is this:

```
Dev
master
remotes/origin/Dev
remotes/origin/master
```

I've tried `git push --all` but that didn't help. I've tried a few other things but I can't remember them all and I'm willing to try them again.

Also, My Dev local branch tracks to the Dev remote branch.

Comment: Duplicate of [Only master branch is visible after cloning a Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889753/only-master-branch-is-visible-after-cloning-a-git-repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provision in Git to do that. The other person will have to create a local copy of your branch by:

```
git checkout -b Dev origin/Dev
```

what this does is to create a local branch named 'Dev' which tracks the remote branch 'origin/Dev'. So essentially, both you and the other person have individual copies of the remote branch. And whenever you or the other person `push`, it gets synced with the remote branch and the other person gets the changes while `pull`ing. This is how Git is supposed to be used.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the workings of Git yet.

Comment: It does take a bit of time to get used to `Git`  :)